# Reaching an Object's Property

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

In my application I have an object with several properties that get set in various places in the application.

In one of my prototype functions I have a function that runs in intervals to update a timer, and in that function the property (this.)theTime should be set. The problem is that this doesn't happen, and I guess the reason is that `this.theTime` points to the function itself instead of the object.

Below is two versions of my code, and neither of them works. Any tips for me?

```
// 1.
function changeTime() {
    this.theTime = setTime(time);
    time.setSeconds(time.getSeconds()+1);
    p1.html(this.theTime);
}
interval = setInterval(changeTime(), 1000 );

// 2.
function changeTime(theTime) {
    theTime = setTime(time);
    time.setSeconds(time.getSeconds()+1);
    p1.html(theTime);
}
interval = setInterval( function() { changeTime(this.theTime); }, 1000 );
```

...

Too make it more clear, the function above updates a timer (eg. `00:00:01` -> `00:00:02`) every second, and I want `this.theTime` to be updated with the time.

When the timer stops (which happens in another prototype function) I want to be able to see what time the timer stopped on, but as it is now `this.theTime` is the default value, which means that the function above doesn't update the objects property. Instead `this.theTime` in the function above must be a local variable.

NOTE: `setTime()` is another function that exists in the same prototype function as the function above.

Comment: What is `this` supposed to be set to?  Your code won't work but without knowing that it's impossible to say exactly how to fix it. The `this` value is set upon each function call; it's not a permanent fixed thing in any function.

Comment: Is `setTime()` a function you wrote or are you trying to use the JS function `Date.setTime()`?

Comment: @JasonCraig I edited the question for you a little more to clean up a few more things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well when you use this in some function `this` is referencing to the object which actually the function is. Here:

```
function myF() {
    this.var = 'hey';
}
```

You can reach `var` using this (myF as a constructor function):

```
var obj = new myF();
alert(obj.var);
```

Or here:

```
function myF2() {
    if (typeof this.var === 'undefined') {
        this.var = 0;
    } else {
        this.var += 1;
    }
    alert(this.var);
}
```

Here `var` again is a property of myF2 (which as I said is not just a function because in JavaScript functions are objects).
Each time you call myF2 this.var is going to be incremented and alerted (just in the first call it's going to be initialized).

In the second function (anonymous function using in the second setInterval) you're doing the same.

One solution is to make theTime global in both cases so you don't need to use:

```
this.theTime
```

So the result can be something like this:

```
var theTime = 0, interval;
function changeTime() {
    theTime += 1;
    document.body.innerHTML = theTime;
    setInterval
}

interval = setInterval(changeTime, 1000 );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u3EuC/

Answer (score 0):

You can verify easily by writting a

```
debugger;
```

to set a breakpoint in your functions. Then it may be pretty easy to find your problem.

Comment: they like fish here, not fishing rod

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your assumption that there's something wrong with your `this` keyword. `this` in JavaScript is a bit tricky, so using it in functions (especially with `setTimeout` or `setInterval` is risky.

What you want to do is save the value of `this` when you create the function.

Here's more information: http://justin.harmonize.fm/index.php/2009/09/an-introduction-to-javascripts-this/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these comments will direct you to the right way

```
var theTime; // global variable
function changeTime() {
    theTime = setTime(time); // theTime is global variable declared above (accesible from anywhere)
    // var myTime = setTime(time); // myTime is local variable
    time.setSeconds(time.getSeconds()+1);
    p1.html(theTime);
}
interval = setInterval(changeTime, 1000 ); // no braces
```

Comment: Beware, if `time.getSeconds()` is `60`, then you do `time.setSeconds(61);`

Comment: @Imre L: ...which is perfectly OK

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, I don't get it? In your code you're declaring the variable "theTime" inside the function. How should I be able to reach that from the other (prototype) functions when I'm not calling any functions from it?

Comment: @Jason Craig: then you should declare `var theTime;` in global scope and use just `theTime = setTime(time)` (without `var`) inside the `changeTime` function (see my updated post). Use `var` keyword in every declaration to protect your code from overwriting global variables.

Comment: But if I declare the variable in the global scope as "var" instead of "this", it won't point at the specific instance?

Comment: @Jason Craig: this would require more space to clarify, see my second answer

Answer (score 0):

Jason, after your clarification, I believe it is better to provide you whole new answer trying to explain **this** statement in JS as good (and simple) as possible. I hope it helps.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="output1"></div>
<div id="output2"></div>
<script>
// theTime is undefined in global scope

function obj(target) {
  var theTime = 0; 
  var that = this; // var means "private"
  this.changeTime = function() { // here "this" points to obj and means "public"
    theTime++; // no var => outer scope = obj scope
    // here "this" points to changeTime function, not to obj!
    // "that" points to obj, you may use that.theTime
    document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = theTime;
  }
}

var o1 = new obj("output1");
var o2 = new obj("output2");

setInterval(o1.changeTime,1000); // update output1 content every second
setInterval(o2.changeTime,500); // update output2 content twice a second
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The comments are oversimplified, so please be indulgent, JS geeks.